# Date conversion in AWS IoT Rule SQL

Tags: aws-iot

I create AWS IoT Rules using Ansible playbook for cloud formation.
Below is snippet where I want to create a simple rule to write everything from updated device shadow to S3. Name of Key should have YYYY/MM/DD.

- Code snippet for IoT Rule SQL:

my_iot_rule:

```
    region: "{{ region }}"
    state: present
    name: "{{ envType }}_deviceshadow_rule_v1"
    description: Forward device shadow status to S3
    sql: SELECT * FROM "${aws}/things/#/shadow/get/accepted" WHERE schemaVersion='mySchemaVersion1.0'
    sqlVersion: "2016-03-23"
    actions:
      - s3:
          roleArn: arn:aws:iam::{{ awsAccount.accountId }}:role/iot-rule-engine
          bucketName: "{{ s3.someBucketName}}"
          "key": "deviceshadow/${device.deviceId}**/YYYY/MM/DD/somename.someextention**"
```

- Assume I have a field with epoch time as "time": 1471618669000 which will be in output of SELECT *,time.
- How do I convert "time": 1471618669000 to get YYYY, MM and DD in "key"'s value in above. Is there any function in IoT SQL ?
- Or How can I get Sysdate in IoT Rule SQL ?
  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Please use:

```
key:${parse_time("yyyy", timestamp())}/${parse_time("MM", timestamp())}/${parse_time("dd", timestamp())}/${parse_time("HH", timestamp())}//${timestamp()}
```

It will create the folder structure like `"year/month/date/hour/file_name"`

Comment: should works, please see `parse_time` examples - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-sql-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

Til today, AWS IOT SQL function has no `date` function. The close solution is to convert epoch to number of days since 1970-1-1, by `deviceshadow/${device.deviceId}/${timestamp()/86400000}/${timestamp()}`.

This will group each event message (unique id as timestamp) by days.

This is still not human readable, and I guess the only way is to use lambda to do the date conversion.